# How to add square brackets in JSON data with python

Tags: python, json

So I have json data that looks like this:

```
"responses":[
{
  "ResponseID" : "R_1mhpDCQzIOlVfPT",
  "ResponseSet" : "Default Response Set",
  "IPAddress" : "",
  "StartDate" : "2016-08-04 11:52:36",
  "EndDate" : "2016-08-04 11:52:53",
  "RecipientLastName" : "",
  "RecipientFirstName" : "",
  "RecipientEmail" : "",
  "ExternalDataReference" : "",
  "Finished" : "1",
  "Status" : "1",
  "Q5" : "",
  "Q6" : "",
  "Q7" : "",
  "Q8" : "",
  "Q9" : "",
  "Q10" : "",
  "Q11" : "",
  "Q12" : "",
  "LocationLatitude" : "33.414794921875",
  "LocationLongitude" : "-111.90930175781",
  "LocationAccuracy" : "-1"
},
```

I basically want to take all of the Q's and put them in a Questions array within the json. The output should look something like this:

```
"responses":[
{
  "ResponseID" : "R_1mhpDCQzIOlVfPT",
  "ResponseSet" : "Default Response Set",
  "IPAddress" : "",
  "StartDate" : "2016-08-04 11:52:36",
  "EndDate" : "2016-08-04 11:52:53",
  "RecipientLastName" : "",
  "RecipientFirstName" : "",
  "RecipientEmail" : "",
  "ExternalDataReference" : "",
  "Finished" : "1",
  "Status" : "1",
  "Questions" : [
     "Q5" : "",
     "Q6" : "",
     "Q7" : "",
     "Q8" : "",
     "Q9" : "",
     "Q10" : "",
     "Q11" : "",
     "Q12" : ""
   ],
  "LocationLatitude" : "33.414794921875",
  "LocationLongitude" : "-111.90930175781",
  "LocationAccuracy" : "-1"
}
```

How could I go about this and apply this to over 100 responses. Here is what I have so far:

```
for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/john/Desktop/Q/QD'):
if filename.endswith(".json") :
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        for i in data['responses']:
            for j in i:
                if j.startswith('Q'):
                    print(j)
        input("Press enter to continue...")
```

All this code does is load the data and basically loops through each file within the folder and prints out all the Questions into the console. How would I go about appending the Questions field and adding the square brackets?

Comment: Shouldn't the questions go into a mapping, not an array?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh what do you mean by mapping? Could you point me to any documentation?

Comment: The json object `{"string": value, "string": value}`

Comment: I see what you mean now, but my biggest problem is appending the actual field Questions to the data. Also I think that a json array will work similarly in this scenario due to the variance of the number of questions per response.

Comment: Don't just `print` some of your data. Alter the data that you have and dump out the transformed data.

Comment: @JackManey That print was just acting as a placeholder. I dumped the data in my code. Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/john/Desktop/Q/QD'):
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as data_file:
            data = json.loads(data_file)
            for response in data['responses']:
                questions = {}
                for key in list(response.keys()):
                    if key.startswith('Q'):
                        questions[key] = response[key]
                        del response[key]

                response['Questions'] = questions
                print(response)
```

Few notes:

1. I'm using python3
2. I'm using `list(response.keys())` to generate copy of the keys, if not, the `del` will error out later when you change the dict while iterating.
3. The magic is just to save your questions in the temp `questions` dict and to appear it later to the response.
4. Just an opinion, you know the input better then I do, but `startswith` might cause you issues when the key starts with "Q" like "quantity" etc

Comment: Thank you for not just answering my question, but for the explanation. This really helps me grasp the concept!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob to Python and had to first fight with validating the JSON, but would something like this work?

Given input:

```
{
    "responses": [{
        "ResponseID": "R_1mhpDCQzIOlVfPT",
        "ResponseSet": "Default Response Set",
        "IPAddress": "",
        "StartDate": "2016-08-04 11:52:36",
        "EndDate": "2016-08-04 11:52:53",
        "RecipientLastName": "",
        "RecipientFirstName": "",
        "RecipientEmail": "",
        "ExternalDataReference": "",
        "Finished": "1",
        "Status": "1",
        "Q5": "",
        "Q6": "",
        "Q7": "",
        "Q8": "",
        "Q9": "",
        "Q10": "",
        "Q11": "",
        "Q12": "",
        "LocationLatitude": "33.414794921875",
        "LocationLongitude": "-111.90930175781",
        "LocationAccuracy": "-1"
    }]
}
```

Using this code:

```
import json

def main():
    f = open('test.json')
    a = json.load(f)
    print a.keys()
    qs = []
    for k in a[u'responses'][0]:
        if 'Q' in k:
            qs.append((k, a[u'responses'][0][k]))
            del k
    a[u'responses'][0]['questions'] = qs
    print a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Gives this output:

```
{u'responses': [{u'Q5': u'', u'Q7': u'', u'Q6': u'', u'Q9': u'', u'Q8': u'', u'ResponseID': u'R_1mhpDCQzIOlVfPT', u'LocationLatitude': u'33.414794921875', u'RecipientLastName': u'', 'questions': [(u'Q5', u''), (u'Q7', u''), (u'Q6', u''), (u'Q9', u''), (u'Q8', u''), (u'Q11', u''), (u'Q10', u''), (u'Q12', u'')], u'Status': u'1', u'StartDate': u'2016-08-04 11:52:36', u'EndDate': u'2016-08-04 11:52:53', u'RecipientEmail': u'', u'Finished': u'1', u'Q11': u'', u'Q10': u'', u'Q12': u'', u'IPAddress': u'', u'RecipientFirstName': u'', u'LocationAccuracy': u'-1', u'LocationLongitude': u'-111.90930175781', u'ExternalDataReference': u'', u'ResponseSet': u'Default Response Set'}]}
```

You'd need to adapt it for your use case.

I'm using Python 2.7 by the way. The previous solution looks a lot more elegant to be honest. I'm posting more to try and help and learn. Feel free to point out my mistakes!